# Keep State of Transaction

Tags: java, jakarta-ee

I have 2 webservice methods :

```
RentCar()
{    
   // Here, i will generate an ID called TransactionID
   // Insert the "TransactionID" into mysql table called Transactions, with another field called RentTime.
}

ReturnCar()
{
   // At some point in time, the user returns the Car.
   // But now i need the "TransactionID" that was generated from RentCar() method.
   // So i could edit the Transactions Table to update a certain field called returnTime.
   // Is that possible ?
}
```

One way I know possible is to create a temporal table and store the values of **RentCar()** into it. Then when the user returns the car, I now remove the values from temp and transfer to **TransactionTable** including the **returntime(now)**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think about how it works in the real life:

1. You rent a car. The renting company creates a record in the transaction table containing the ID of the car that has been rented, **and gives you the car**.
2. You get back one week later **with the car**. The rent company searches for the record in the transaction table **containing the ID of the returned car**, and can now mark this record as returned.

So, in your code, simply do the same thing: return a transaction ID from the `rentCar()` service, and take it as argument in the `returnCar()` service. You're not "returning". You're returning **a specific car**, identified by the transactionID.